# Okhttp3 com.square does not exist

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8, okhttp

I am using Netbeans and I've created java project with Maven. I added this dependency.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It worked, I could import com.squareup.okhttp.*. After seeing some code on the web I realized that many people are using the version 3+. I tried to change the package to:

**updated**
  I've typed groupid wrongly in the question "com.squareup.okhttp" but in my code it was right "com.squareup.okhttp3".

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
<artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
<version>3.9.0</version>
```

But I couldn't import com.squareup.okhttp3 ( package com.squareup does not exist). Why? I am new to the Java language itself and all the IDEs and tools that support it.

Comment: I made I mistake in my code the groupid is right. I will update the question.

Comment: I figured it out. The import is just okhttp3: "import okhttp3" without com.square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The import is just okhttp3: "import okhttp3" without com.square.

Answer (score 3):

Okhttp3 does not exist is due to a bug in Intellij IDE; however, there is a get-around:

1. Place your 'com.squareup.okhttp3' dependency block at the end of the 'dependencies' list in the pom.xml file.
2. 'import okhttp3...' is the right thing to to in your Java file.

pom.xml:

```
        ...
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
           <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
           <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Java file:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct coordinates for okhttp3 are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the groupId has changed from `com.squareup.okhttp` to `com.squareup.okhttp3`.

So, if you update your pom.xml, replacing what you had for `okhttp` with what I posted above then you'll be able to resolve the `okhttp` classes.

For future reference you can find the `okhttp` artifacts on [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp).

Comment: Thanks @glytching for spotting my mistake but in my code the dependency is set right.